# Entropy for a discrete multivariate variable?

Tags: discrete-data, entropy

Suppose I have a multivariate discrete random variable $Y=(Y_1,\dots , Y_n)$, where $Y_{i}$'s are independent and not identically distributed Binomial variables. How can one calculate the entropy of $Y$?

Comment: There is a finite number of possible values (maybe large). The entropy only depends upon the probabilities, not on the structure of the possibel values set.  So there is nothing special about the multivariate case, calculation is the same as univariate case, same formula.  You only need to calculate all the $p_i$'s

Comment: Is joint entropy what you are looking for? [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_entropy)